# SharePoint 2013 Full Crawl never stops

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, crawling

I have set the following inside the content sources:

- Incremental crawl to be every 20 minutes
- Full crawl: At 1:00 every day.

When I first set this it was working well, the incremental crawl take between 2-3 minutes and the full crawl take around 30 minutes.

But I check the search service lately and I so that the full crawl duration is 134 hours and when I manually stop it, it restart again and never stops.

Can anyone advice, why my full crawl is not stopping?

Comment: I am having the same issue and found the following in our ULS log repeating over and over: A database error occurred. Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider Code: 220 occurred 0 time(s) Description:  Error ordinal: 1 Message: Arithmetic overflow error for data type smallint, value = 32768.  I am going to try an Index Reset next and see if that helps.  Please post if you have found a solution.

Comment: I have the same problem.
I also get the error Arithmetic overflow error for data type smallint, value = 32768
Index reset an changing the search topology didn't fix the problem for me. I don't want to recreate the search service Application. @Trent did you already found a solution for this issue?

Comment: Please restart the search service from windows and do a IIS reset. Restart the Full Crawl and check.

Comment: Is there anything unusual in the crawl logs (for the content sources, not ULS)?

Comment: I had a similar problem with search threads. Ended up solving the problem with a hammer. `while (1)  { Stop-Process -Name noderunner -Force -Verbose ; Sleep -S 100 }`

Comment: Restart SharePoint search service(s) and start the Full Crawl

Answer (score 3):

Just went through this issue with **Microsoft** last week.

You'll need to go into `Central Admin > Manage Service Applications`

Then you'll have to `delete` and `re-provision` your **Search Service Application**.

More info on reprovisioning using PowerShell [can be found here.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/11076/re-provisoning-sharepoint-service-applications-using-powersh.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Reboot the server, do also clear your configuration cache and that should fix the issue. It did for me most of the times.

Answer (score 2):

We just went through the same issue.

Have a look at your CrawlStore SQL database, in the MSSCrawlURL table. I bet there is a row with an "ErrorCount" of exactly 32767.

Sharepoint seems to increment this by 1 for each failure, and given that column is of smallint type, it fails to increment it past that point.

In my case I determined that the item in question no longer needed crawling, so I added a crawl rule to exclude it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check the ULS log for more detailed error information. As this issue could occur by many reason.
The ULS log is located at the path:

```
c:\program files\common files\Microsoft shared\web server extensions\14\LOGS
```

You can use ULS viewer to check it.

Answer (score 1):

Usually in this case the following should help:
- stopping all crawls (if possible)
- restart of Search Host Controller on each server which is used in topology
- starting the crawls

I don't know the reason why crawls go to never ending mode, however, this search host controller restart seems to be the best solution that is not as much influencing SharePoint as reset of IIS or Index reset.

Answer (score 1):

In my installation this behavior was caused by a hard disk running full. 
Sharepoint writes into the `/Index` folder and it can grow rather large.

In the moment I freed some space (by deleting some logfiles), the crawler would immediately stop and it freed about 2/3 of the space allocated in that directory.

All the other solutions with restarting, IIS reset and so on would not work for me. 
Some people reported that deleting the search application helped - but I guess that is just a way to free some space (I was hesitant to do this).

Answer (score 0):

Try to stop the crawl via powershell forcefully. Reboot your server. Initiate a full crawl.

Comment: Can you provide more information regarding stopping a crawl with PowerShell?

Comment: Or a more simpler approach, without any headache, simply create a new search service application and delete the old one after recreating. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee704549(v=office.15).aspx--for stopping the search using powershell.

Comment: @RobertLindgren, here is the link for Stopping the Crawl usingPowerShell :  http://get-spscripts.com/2012/05/force-stop-and-then-start-full-crawl-on.html

Answer (score -1):

I had the same experience in sharepoint 2007 cralwer. i did the following this to overcome this issue.

1. First restart the timer job
2. Reset the IIS Server

I will not stop immediately and i don't know the reason for that. after around 2hrs all seems working fine.