# Couldn't activate my feature because my ClientTag had reached 32767

Tags: feature-activation, bug

While deploying my solution in visual studio in my development environment I came across a very strange issue. While uploading some master pages defined in my an `Elements.xml` file, the deployment threw an exception

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 0x81020030 The URL '_catalogs/masterpage/IntranetMaster.html' is invalid.  It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web.

After some research and checking the ULS logs I saw this exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Arithmetic overflow error for data type smallint, value = 32768
>
> ExecuteQuery failed with original error 0x80131904
>
> SQL error code from last error 220 - Arithmetic overflow error for data type smallint, value = 32768.

I scanned the SharePoint content database for `smallint` columns with high values and found that the `ClientTag` column inside the `AllSites` table had a value of 32767.

I updated the value to 16000 and my deployment works as expected. It seems like every time I deploy, this number increases in value and eventually it has increased to the maximum value of smallint.

Has anyone experienced this before? What have I done wrong? Is this a bug in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 0):

soniiic,

I did a cursory glance online to see what others are saying about this error. The consensus so far has been a problem with a Search Service crawl that hangs. Check and see if this applies to you and let me know what you find. I'm eager to help.

See here:

[The Never-Ending Crawl (part 1)](http://sharepointwoo.com/the-never-ending-crawl-part-1/)

[SharePoint 2013 Full Crawl never stops](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79063/sharepoint-2013-full-crawl-never-stops)

You could also try [renaming the masterpage](http://prashamsabadra.blogspot.com/2014/02/the-url-is-invalid-it-may-refer-to.html) that is being uploaded. That seems to be what others have tried as a work around.

Jim

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I don't have the search service installed

Comment: just updated my answer