# Search Crawls will not stop - SharePoint 2016 On-Premise

Tags: 2016, crawling, crawl, timer-service

I am having an issue with the search crawlers not stopping - they run with the status at "Crawling Full" status for days (125 hours, 271 hours, etc.) before I just stop them.

What I have done so far (Not necessarily in this order) -

1. Stopped and started all SharePoint Search Services on the servers
2. Cleared the server cache
3. Changed the Content Source to point only to the root (there was another URL in the list that was suspect)

does anyone have any suggestions for how to resolve this?

Thank you - any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with trying some of the solutions [SharePoint 2013 Full Crawl never stops](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79063/sharepoint-2013-full-crawl-never-stops).

In particular...

[Check the ULS Logs for more information on the App server(s)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/165988/77489) via `c:\program files\common files\Microsoft shared\web server extensions\<VERSION>\LOGS` and you may find more information on the issue.

---

If that doesn't help, I'd try [Clearing the cache and rebooting](https://www.zubairalexander.com/blog/clearing-the-sharepoint-configuration-cache/) using these steps:

1. Stopping the `SharePoint Timer Service` on all servers
2. Navigate to `%SystemDrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config` and enter the folder with a hyphenated GUID like `42d05b3f-d221-4f69-845e-3f5bab1a4634` as a name.
3. Delete all files within that folder **EXCEPT** for `cache.ini`. For safe measures, I'd back up that file as we'll modify it later. (link states you can copy/paste into same folder to create a `- copy` file.
4. Now delete all the `.xml` files (sort by document type to make sure you don't select the `.ini` file.
5. Open the `config.ini` and replace the large number inside with the number 1.
6. Repeat 2-5 for each server
7. Restart the `SharePoint Timer Service` on all servers.

The services will start to repopulate the configuration cache and will likely have a different number than what was in the original `cache.ini`.

---

As more of a last resort, try [Re provisioning the search service](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/130759/77489) by deleting it and building the new service through `Central Admin > Manage Service Applications`.

Comment: I had the problem the last time I built a SharePoint VM development server.  The "last resort" was the only thing that fixed it.

Comment: I actually did steps 1-7 already on all servers ... this did not help - would an IIS reset be necessary?  Or restarting the servers?

Comment: @Anngela It shouldn't be necessary. You can try an IIS reset and see if that helps. However, as willman said in a previous comment he had to do the 'last resort' option to fix this.

Comment: @willman - could you please elaborate a little more on this "The "last resort" was the only thing that fixed it. " we are also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

First check what is the state of each database of search service from the search service administration page in CA -  then try to follow the below :

- Clear Cache in all App servers , Index Reset and start full crawl.
- Restarting the servers.

If that does not resolve, check the below :

- C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
  Extensions\16\LOGS
- Restart SharePoint Server search  service
- Restart SharePoint Timer Service
- Restart IIS

If the above steps doesn't resolve issue, try to run configuration wizard in App server but ensure while running the configuration wizard take all necessary backups.

Finally, if nothing works -  need to create a new search service application and we can delete the old one, here while recreating the new SA, we can reuse the same search service db in order to retain all configuration.

Comment: a new content source (test) was created for the search service using the root URL that completed a full crawl in just over an hour (it literally is set up the same way as the original with a different name) ... not sure why that one is working but the original does not.